# single sign on for multiple nodejs applications

Tags: node.js, single-sign-on, passport.js

We have 3 nodejs web application running on same domain name on same vps with multiple subdomains and implementing passport authentication for each. We wanted single user be able to access all application with single account and for that we have added accounts.example.com as fourth application solely for purpose of account management. The requirement is - once user is authenticated in accounts.example.com, how to enable user to access rest of the three web application with that session.

Answer (score 2):

you can share your session in redis-server.if you use express,you can try to use connect-redis
https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis

Answer (score 2):

Try Hands on CanSecurity... It tops the chart for node.js Single sign on.. Hope this proves fruitful https://github.com/deitch/cansecurity