# Implementing single authentication for multiple node apps using Feathersjs as server

Tags: node.js, api, express, server, feathersjs

Is it possible to implement single authentication for multiple Node apps using FeathersJS Node API? How will this be implemented?

Comment: Maybe? No one is going to do it for you, though. What have you tried?

Comment: Looking at creating an identity for each client on the server. Each call from a client will be sent with authentication data {email : '',password: '',clientId: ''}. This should make the server recognise which client is making the call

Comment: Remember: SO is not a threaded forum, and comments are not for question details. Go ahead and [edit] your question and expand on it based on comments for clarification. Make sure you review [ask] and especially [mcve] and certainly take the [tour].

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20696468/1531971 https://stackoverflow.com/q/43631581/1531971 and others. This looks like a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do single sign-on with NodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43631581/how-to-do-single-sign-on-with-nodejs)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41076627/evaluating-featherjs-authentication-needs/41095638#41095638 is also relevant